# Ignoring ChatState packets in a chat and loggin chatstates in console in SMACK

Tags: java, smack

I have developed a simple chat client which sends and receives messages as well as user typing CHatState notificationbetween 2 users - userx and usery. In the debug window I see the packets either containing body or with the chatstate. All the packets are being logged correctly.

**Problem 1 :** But my window is showing both in the chat(JLabel). Because of this, Whenever a user starts typing, the other user sees a null message in his window, which is actually a packet containing the chat state notification without any body. I have tried various conditions, but all have failed. I tried the following ridiculous if condition, yet it displays the null packets.

```
if (message != null || message.getBody().isEmpty() == false
                    || message.getBody() != null
                    || message.getBody().toString().compareTo("null") == 1
                                            && message.getError() == null)
```

**Problem 2:** I'm unable to log the notification chat states which are sent. My code goes as follows :

```
import java.applet.Applet;

public class ChatBoard extends JFrame implements MessageListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    static String username, password;
    static XMPPConnection connection;
    private JTextField textField;
    static JLabel board = new JLabel("<html>");
    static Chat chat;
    String message;
    static ChatState status;
    static String to;
    static boolean flag = false;
    JLabel typingStat;

    public class typingStatus implements ChatStateListener {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(Chat arg0, ChatState arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            System.out.println(arg1.name());

        }

        @Override
        public void processMessage(Chat arg0, Message arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println(arg1.getBody());

        }

    }

    public void sendChat(String msg) {
        try {
            to = "harsh00008";
            if (username.compareTo(to) == 0)
                to = "usery@xyz";
            else
                to = "userx@xyz";

            chat = connection.getChatManager().createChat(to, this);

            chat.sendMessage(msg);
        } catch (XMPPException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void changeStatus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (username.compareTo("harsh00008") == 0)
            chat = connection.getChatManager().createChat("test@prc.p1.im",
                    this);
        else
            chat = connection.getChatManager().createChat(
                    "harsh00008@prc.p1.im", this);

        if (textField.getText().isEmpty() == false && flag == false) {
            try {
                ChatStateManager.getInstance(connection).setCurrentState(
                        ChatState.composing, ChatBoard.chat);

                flag = true;
            } catch (XMPPException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            if (textField.getText().isEmpty() == true && flag == true) {
                try {
                    ChatStateManager.getInstance(connection).setCurrentState(
                            ChatState.paused, ChatBoard.chat);

                    flag = false;
                } catch (XMPPException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }

    public ChatBoard(String user, String pass) {

        setVisible(true);

        username = user;
        password = pass;

        //JFRAME CREATION CODE OMITTED



        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                changeStatus();

            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                changeStatus();

            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                changeStatus();

            }
        });


        sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (textField.getText().isEmpty() == false) {
                    sendChat(textField.getText().toString());
                    board.setText(board.getText() + "<br>me : "
                            + textField.getText());
                    changeStatus();
                    textField.setText("");
                }

            }
        });

        JLabel info = new JLabel("Press Enter or click");

        JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setVisible(false);
                WelcomeUser w = new WelcomeUser();
                connection.disconnect();
                w.setVisible(true);
            }
        });


        // ////////////////////////////////////////////

        XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;

        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                "prc.p1.im", 5222, "prc.p1.im");

        connection = new XMPPConnection(config);

        try {
            connection.connect();

        } catch (XMPPException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Not Connected. Error :" + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            connection.login(username, password);

        } catch (XMPPException e) {

            flag = false;

            textField.setVisible(false);
            sendButton.setVisible(false);

            info.setText("Invalid Login!");

            welcomeLabel.setText("Invalid user!");

        }

        connection.getChatManager().addChatListener(new ChatManagerListener() {

            public void chatCreated(final Chat chat,
                    final boolean createdLocally) {

                chat.addMessageListener(new MessageListener() {

                    public void processMessage(Chat chat, final Message message) {
                        try {
                            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    String sender = message.getFrom();
                                    if (username.compareTo("usery") == 0)
                                        sender = "h";
                                    else
                                        sender = "t";

                                    if (message != null
                                            || message.getBody().isEmpty() == false
                                            || message.getBody() != null
                                            || message.getBody().toString()
                                                    .compareTo("null") == 1
                                            && message.getError() == null)
                                        board.setText(board.getText()
                                                + "<br> <font color=red>"
                                                + sender
                                                + " </font>:<font color=black> "
                                                + message.getBody() + "</font>");
                                    URL url = getClass().getResource(
                                            "resource/ultrakill_ultimate.wav");
                                    AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
                                    clip.play();
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                });

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void processMessage(Chat arg0, Message arg1) {

        message = arg1.getBody();
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                }
            });
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**Details:** 
Normal message packets are like this :

```
<message id="5KE6T-11" to="usery@xyz" from="userx@xyz/Smack" type="chat">
  <body>hi people</body>
  <thread>fqw5912</thread>
  <active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/>
</message>
```

Chat State packets are like this :

```
<message id="IgIbv-13" to="userx@xyz" from="usery@xyz/Smack" type="chat">
  <thread>fqw5913</thread>
  <composing xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/>
</message>
```

**Screenshot :** 
[image]

Any comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You are right, that condition is ridiculous, and very wrong.

```
if (message != null || message.getBody().isEmpty() == false
                        || message.getBody() != null
                        || message.getBody().toString().compareTo("null") == 1
                                                && message.getError() == null)
```

There will always be a message passed in, thus message will never be null and this condition will always pass, which is a good thing since it will throw a NPE if the body is null.

What you are trying to do is this:

```
if (message.getBody() != null)  // getBody() returns null if there is no body so check for empty is unnecessary.
```

All the other checks are either uneccessary or redundant.

2) You don't actually create your ChatStateListener or register it with the Chat (addMessageListener).  That is why you don't receive the chat state messages.

In addition to these, you are creating a new Chat every time you send a message or the DocumentListener is called.  I don't think this is what you actually want.  I would think you want to send and receive on the same Chat.

**Hints and Tips**

There are also a lot of glaring issues with your code with respect to coding standards so I will also add some tips (please don't take this as an insult, I am simply trying to help you with your Java skills).

```
if (<boolean condition> == false) // It is already evaluated to true or false
```

should be

```
if (!<boolean condition>)
```

for example

```
if (message.getBody().isEmpty() == false)
```

should be

```
if (!message.getBody().isEmpty())
```

Also
    if ( == true)

should be

```
if (<boolean condition>)
```

- Don't mix your inner classes with methods, either put them all before
  or after.
- Class names ALWAYS start with a capital letter.
- Don't use static variables for instance based data.

Comment: Hi Robin, Thanks a lot for replying. I will take it constructively. Will try out whatever you are saying and accept your answer. I appreciate your help. I'm kind of new to this stuff so don't worry, my skills area already low.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, you may refer to this example for using ChatStateListener :

```
/**
* 
* listening for chat state change from server and change that state in
* model
* 
* */
private class DefaultChatStateListener implements ChatStateListener {

public void stateChanged(Chat user, ChatState event) {
    System.out.println("Getting called here...");
    System.out.println(user.getParticipant() + " is " + event.name());

    String state = event.name();
    TypingStateType typingState = null;
    if (state.equals("active")) {
        typingState = TypingStateType.ACTIVE;
    } else if (state.equals("composing")) {
        typingState = TypingStateType.TYPING;
    } else if (state.equals("paused")) {
        typingState = TypingStateType.PAUSED;
    } else if (state.equals("inactive")) {
        typingState = TypingStateType.INACTIVE;
    } else if (state.equals("gone")) {
        typingState = TypingStateType.GONE;
    }
    controller.typingStateUpdated(genericConnection, typingState, user
            .getParticipant().toString());
}

public void processMessage(Chat arg0, Message arg1) {
    // Do nothing

}

}
```

Using the DefaultChatStateListener :

```
lastChat = connection.getChatManager().createChat(
                                    connection.getHost(),
                                    new DefaultChatStateListener());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler demo that you can refer to:

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManagerListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws XMPPException {
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("127.0.0.1", 5222);
        XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);             
        connection.connect();       
        connection.login("userx", "123456");    
        ChatManager cm = connection.getChatManager();   
        Chat chat = cm.createChat("usery", null);   
        /**
         * add listener
         */
        cm.addChatListener(new ChatManagerListener() {
            @Override
            public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean create) {
                chat.addMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message msg) {
                        System.out.println(chat.getParticipant() + ":" + msg.getBody());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        chat.sendMessage("test");   
        while(true);            //keep this chat
        //connection.disconnect();  
    }
}
```